# Netty 4.1.2 dynamic pipeline change

Tags: netty, pipeline

i'm currently workin on a websocket server based on netty. I tried to implemnt a login feature, but i have some issues with it.
My initialized pipeline is the following:

```
pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketServerCompressionHandler());
pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler(WEBSOCKET_PATH, null, true));
pipeline.addLast(new RequestHandler(WEBSOCKET_PATH));
pipeline.addLast("HandlerLogin", new FrameHandlerLogin());
```

After a succuessful login, the FrameHandlerLogin should change the pipeline and i thought this lines would do the job, but nothing changes:

```
ctx.pipeline().addLast("HandlerSQL", new FrameHandlerSQL());
ctx.pipeline().remove("HandlerLogin");
```

Is there a misstake or is there some additonal work to do?

Thanks, Schere

ok so more detailed:
I mainly use the websocket example provided by netty. The server is started with:

```
erverBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                .childHandler(new PipelineInitializer(sslCtx));

        Channel ch = bootstrap.bind("localhost",PORT).sync().channel();

        System.out.println("Open your web browser and navigate to " + "https" + "://127.0.0.1:" + PORT + '/');

        ch.closeFuture().sync();
```

The PipelineInitializer initalizes all the handlers listed above. Runnig the application and connecting via firefox is no problem. entering username and password also works. The FramHandlerLogin does the following:

```
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, WebSocketFrame frame) throws Exception {
    String recievedUser;
    String recievedPsw;

    if (frame instanceof TextWebSocketFrame) {
        String request = ((TextWebSocketFrame) frame).text();
        JSONObject in = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(request);
        recievedUser = (String) in.get("user");
        recievedPsw = (String) in.get("psw");
        if (recievedUser.equals(USER) && recievedPsw.equals(PASSWORD)) {
            System.out.println("Recieved correct User and Password!");


            ctx.pipeline().addLast("HandlerSQL", new FrameHandlerSQL());
            ctx.pipeline().remove("HandlerLogin");

            ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame("Success"));


        } else {
//some error handling
```

so far so good. The websocket requests /sql.html if he recieves "Success"

The RequestHandler now logs the uri and the pipeline to the console.

```
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest req) throws Exception {
    // Handle a bad request.
    ...

    // Allow only GET methods.
    ...

//TODO Debug remove
//after a successfull client login, the requested uri should be sql.html
//also the pipeline should use the FrameHandlerSQL and not the FrameHandlerLogin. 
//The problem is, that the FrameHAndlerLogin is still active and the FrameHandlerSql is not
    System.out.println("URI:" + req.uri() );
    if(ctx.pipeline().get("HandlerLogin") != null){
        System.out.println("Piepline: Login" );
    } else if(ctx.pipeline().get("HandlerSQL") != null) {
        System.out.println("Piepline: SQL");
    }
    // Send the index page
    if ("/".equals(req.uri()) || "/index.html".equals(req.uri())) {
        String webSocketLocation = getWebSocketLocation(ctx.pipeline(), req, websocketPath);
        ByteBuf content = null;
        content = PageLoaderLogin.getContent(webSocketLocation);
        FullHttpResponse res = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK, content);
        res.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        HttpUtil.setContentLength(res, content.readableBytes());
        sendHttpResponse(ctx, req, res);

} else if ("/sql.html".equals(req.uri())) {
        String webSocketLocation = getWebSocketLocation(ctx.pipeline(), req, websocketPath);
        ByteBuf content = null;
        content = PageLoaderSQL.getContent(webSocketLocation);
        FullHttpResponse res = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK, content);
        res.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        HttpUtil.setContentLength(res, content.readableBytes());
        sendHttpResponse(ctx, req, res);
    } else {
        sendHttpResponse(ctx, req, new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, NOT_FOUND));
    }
}
```

It says that the login was successfull, but the piepline at the next request is still the old one, as you can see in the comments near RequestHandler.

Is the context the same for all requests? or is a new context created for every request? I think that could be the problem?

Schere

Comment: nope this is all you should do... What does not work and how you know it not works ? Please add more details

Comment: I edited the post above.

Comment: I still not see where you explain what exacly not works and why you think it not works as expected.

Comment: edited it again. but the problem could be, that the context is allways created new for each request, right?

Comment: The pipeline should be the same as long as you're using the same SocketChannel instance for the subsequent requests.